# Add custom config into AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, appsflyer-cordova-sdk

I am using cordova and one third party plugin which has a block of setting missing from AndroidManifest.xml file. 
I have checked custom-config from npm but still can't figure out how to enter the following code from config.xml into the xml file.

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The thing is that this should be read from config.xml and added on each platform wipe.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a `edit-config` tag in your config.xml. See the example in the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config)...

Comment: Assuming you want to add your code to the root node of AndroidManifest.xml the tag could look like this `<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="*" mode="merge">
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</edit-config>`

Comment: Hi @Phonolog it's close. So I want to basicly add this reciever under application tag, so i had to modify target="/*/application". It adds as a separate block there now, but i have another issue. It also adds android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver" inside <application tag> and <supports-screens> tag which brakes the config.

Comment: I will remove the platform completely and re-try again as I think this might be some caching issue. Will take a look and go under acceptance of your answer sooner.

Comment: Hmm if you're having trouble with a collision of different tags you could also try to set `mode="overwrite"` as also described in the docs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a [`<config-file>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file) block to your `config.xml`:

```
<widget>
    ...
    <platform name="android">
        ...
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
            <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </config-file>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Since `cordova@8`, `<config-file>` blocks are supported in `config.xml` (in addition to a plugin's `plugin.xml`).

Comment: I got this error : cordova-custom-config: Error updating config for platform 'android': Cannot use absolute path on element. I think parent="/manifest/application" is wrong.

Comment: so <config-file parent="application" target="AndroidManifest.xml"> did work for me, but now i got an error under android build : AAPT: error: unbound prefix. it is pointing to this line #42 <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver">

Comment: uninstall `cordova-custom-config` - you don't need it for this - Cordova itself will parse the `<config-file>` block. But you must have an old version of `cordova-custom-config` installed, because since `cordova-custom-config@5` it only parses `<custom-config-file>` - [see here](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#changes-in-cordova-custom-config5)

Comment: so I had to add xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" under the reciever tag in order to get rid of the 'under android build : AAPT: error: unbound prefix' error. I am not sure why android:name was not recognized without this xmlns value.

Comment: when i used **edit-config** with target="/manifest/application" in config.xml, it added the elements to 2 tags "manifest" and "application" in file AndroidManifest. Something is wrong? thanks